# Can I use 50mm f2 lens to take building photos?

Tags: lens, film, 35mm

Can I use 50mm f2 lens to take building photos?
In my case will be an Yashica ML 50mm f/2.

Comment: Step outside your house, and take a photo. Then deciide if that kind of picture is the one you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take building photos with any lens you have. The biggest tradeoff is in perspective - if you have a relatively long lens, the perspective is completely different than a wide-angle lens because you have to step back farther to get the entire building in. Only you can decide exactly what type of look you are aiming for.

There are other tradeoffs, too - depth of field, the possibilities of foreground obstructions, etc. But you as the artist have to make the call on exactly what you're trying to capture.

Answer (score 4):

> Can I use 50mm f2 lens to take building photos? In my case will be an Yashica ML 50mm f/2.

Yes. Yes you can.

Answer (score 1):

The 50mm is the most flexible lens you can get. You can photograph anything you want, with maybe subpar results.

If you have old lenses, you can even make them become a tilt-shift one with [one of these adapters](https://fotodioxpro.com/collections/lens-mount-adapters/tlt-rokr). Tilt-shift capabilities can be pretty handy for real estate.

However, if you plan on taking pictures inside, or in a narrow street, the 50mm lens may be a little too tight. In a full-frame sensor something around 30-25mm, or 15-20mm on APS-C, may give you better outcomes with fewer post-production techniques (panorama stitching and so) without the wide lens typical aberrations (barrel distortions and such).
I would also not be extra picky with maximum apertures for real estate photography, as with a tripod you can get pretty much any shot with ISO 100 and a narrow aperture just by increasing the shutter time, helping depth of field. Buildings are pretty steady! For that reason, maybe a zoom lens can be easier to handle...

My favorite zoom lens is the Sigma DC 17-50 f/2.8 OS HSM, and in the wide end it yields pretty good results.

Answer (score 1):

Lenses are fitted to cameras based on need. What you need to know is what focal length will be considered telephoto, normal, or wide-angle.

A normal lens is multipurpose. The normal is popular because it delivers a perspective that is the counterpart  of how we see the world. A wide-angle lens has an expanded field-of-view. They are most useful when it is impossible for us to backup to increase camera to subject distance. A telephoto yields a magnified view. They are essential when we want detail while working from afar.

So the real question is: For my camera body, what focal lengths fit these categories?

A normal lens is one with a focal length that about matches the corner to corner measure of my cameras format. The venerable 35mm full frame measures 24mm height by 36mm length. It is customary to mount a lens with a 50mm focal length and label this lash-up as normal. The realm of wide-angle is 35mm or shorter. Telephoto territory is 100mm or longer.

If you are using a compact digital, the frame size is 16mm height by 24mm length. This is about 66% of the size of the full frame. For this format a 30mm is deemed normal, 20mm or shorter is wide-angle and 60mm or longer is telephoto.

Can you photograph buildings with a 50mm? The answer is yes indeed. All you need do is compose by adjusting your camera to subject distance until you are pleased with the framing. 
As to perspective – most shots of objects like buildings or landscapes are not affected if the perspective is off. Sometimes perspective errors enhance the chosen subject matter. This is the province of experience and this is usually an acquired skill.